# How to register/make a Callback function to inform all Fragments an action has been taken?

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, callback, asynccallback

I have a class singleton to make a auth on web service, in each fragment I need load data from web, so I need know if service has logged or not, in MainActivity I call the login function, but the fragments load together, so the webservice not loggin at yet. So, in each fragment I wants call function with callback to know when login is finished to dowload the content.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreateView()");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product,container,false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        initUI(view);
        return view;
    }

    public void initUI(View v) {
        spinnerProducts = v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerProducts);

        // Here I wants load content.

    }
```

Main:

```
 mOdoo.init(this, new CallbackOdooLogin() {
            @Override
            public void onOdooLogin(boolean isLog) {
                Log.i(TAG,"onOdooLogin(): " + isLog);
                if( isLog ) {
                    // Here inform all fragments!
                } else {
                    // or here.
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: create one an abstract class which extends fragment create one abstract method init. then when  you finish oddologin find fragment by id or name and cast to your abstract class. you will find abstract method which use for load your content

Comment: You can let me see a sample?